# Clojure - Indexing elements of an Array

Tags: arrays, clojure, indexing

I have an array of elements that has been divided up into groups although I need to make reference to each grouping specifically using a letter for each. So far I have sorted and split the array but I am unsure of what the next step would be or if there is a more intuitive way to process this, my steps so far are below:

```
data(map(keyword :counter)querieddata)
sortedlist(sort > tosort)
part(into [] (partition-all (/ (count data) 10) sortedlist))
```

Ideally I'd like my output to be something like:

```
[(:a 40 40 36 33) (:b 33 30 27 25) (:c 25 19 18 5)]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do you know the letters you want to use for each group beforehand?

Comment: yes - i just want to use a thru i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [zipmap](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/zipmap)

```
 user=> (zipmap [:a :b :c :d :e] [1 2 3 4 5])
 {:e 5, :d 4, :c 3, :b 2, :a 1}
```

In your particular case the second list is the grouped results

```
 user=> (zipmap [:a :b :c :d :e] [[1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]])
 {:c [7 8 9], :b [4 5 6], :a [1 2 3]}
```